# Error when using react hooks and transferable objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-worker

I have a hook `useWorker` which manages a worker. Inside of it i would like to declare something like:

```
const foo = useRef(new Float32Array(myBufferRef.current))
```

However, this runs fine once, then an effect runs that posts a message with `foo.current.buffer` as a transferable object, and then i get:

```
useWorker.tsx:146 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot perform Construct on a detached ArrayBuffer
```

It's basically complaining about this `useRef` (but it fails at `useState`).

How could i instantiate an `ArrayBuffer` a `Float32Array` using it, on a component mount and transfer it to the worker and back during the component's lifetime?

Comment: Would a [SharedArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer/) be an option for your project? I.E are you in a COOP + COEP compliant document? This way you wouldn't need to transfer it.

Comment: No unfortunately, transferables do the trick, but i haven't gone past just having a mutable variable outside of react.

Comment: I had some luck with using a weak map and caching these views by my workers handlers which are static. But still am curious why I can’t use the sugar from react.